# Javascript Select Multiple Images of same Class

Tags: javascript

I have written a javscript code but I can't get it work for some reason :(

Basically, I have a gallery that loads multiple images, but I want to limit it to 6 pictures only.
Those images have all the same classes.
I want to select each image and put "display:none" until there's only 6 left then stop.

Here's the code:

```js
<script>
    var storyCount = document.querySelectorAll(".e-gallery-item.elementor-gallery-item");

    
    for(var i = 6; i < storyCount.length; i++)
    storyCount[i].style.display='none';

</script>
```

For some reason it doesn't work :(
Any suggestion?

Any help is appreciated! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work, because `storyCount` isn't an array. Its an `object` which is returned from `document.querySelectorAll`. So you need to modify condition of `for` loop like this

```
<script>
    var storyCount = document.querySelectorAll(".e-gallery-item.elementor-gallery-item");

    
    for(var i = 6; i < Object.entries(storyCount).length; i++)
      storyCount[i].style.display='none';

</script>
```

See my demo example

```js
const storyCount = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
console.log(typeof storyCount)
for(let i = 6; i < Object.entries(storyCount).length; i++)
  storyCount[i].style.display='none';
```

```css
.image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="image" />
<img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="image" />
<img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="image" />
<img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="image" />
<img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="image" />
<img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="image" />
<img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="image" />
<img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="image" />
<img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="image" />
<img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="image" />
<img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="image" />
<img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var storyCount = document.querySelectorAll(".e-gallery-item.elementor-gallery-item");


for (var i = 0; i < storyCount.length; i++)
  storyCount[i].style.display = 'none';

for (var i = 1; i < Math.min(storyCount.length, 6); i++)
  storyCount[i].style.display = 'block';
```

Will this work?